# Trignometry - Cos

Tags: systems-of-equations, regular-expressions

If $\cos54 = t$, determine $\cos144$ in terms of $t$?

What I've done so far is $\cos54=t$, $\cos144 = 2t-18$?
Quite lost with this equation, should I have a look at some identities, and is my answer completely incorrect?

Comment: How did you get $\cos 144=2t-18$?

Comment: Hint: $144=90+54.$ Do you know any identity involving $\cos(90+ \theta)$ ?

Comment: Thank you! Haven't done this in ages. Just needed your hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$\cos 144=\cos(90+54)=\cos 90\cos 54-\sin 90\sin54=-\sin 54.$$ Now, $$\sin 54 =\sqrt{1-\cos^2 54}=\sqrt{1-t^2}.$$ So, the answer is

$$\cos 144=-\sqrt{1-t^2}.$$

Comment: Indeed. Just to add to that: $t$ can be given in explicit terms using radians: $t=\cos(3\pi/10)=1/4\cdot\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}$.

Comment: @BerndH: how does using radians help find this non-obvious identity ???

Comment: Sorry, your're right in pointing out that "using" was not the right term. Actually deriving the result for cos(54°) obviously does not depend on that. You might use multiple angles, sine and some "well known" trigonometric identies or the regular pentagon and the "golden ratio".